USA to CA transfer
I am located in Canada. My friend was sending me some money. She is located in South Carolina and sending via bank to bank transfer. Transfer was made two weeks ago and still has not been received on my end but shows completed on hers. I have provided the account number and the routing number. Her bank says it should have taken 72 hours, while my bank on the receiving end says about 10 business days which would have been yesterday due holidays and weekends.
How long normally should a wire transfer take from the states to Canada?

I'd say 10 business days given what your bank said, plus another day or two for internal processing.  It sounds like this is an issue with your bank.

Is this a person you actually have a history with? Someone you’ve only talked to online?

I get wire transfers from the States regularly. When they work, they take WAY less than 10 days. They do sometimes "get stuck" and I contact "my guy" at the bank, and after a week or so they sometimes magically appear. I think what happens is the sender cancels and re-sends. So you're not necessarily being scammed, but these delays are not normal.

Yes the person is a friend a good friend she's like a sister. To me.  On her side the bank says completed but never did show up on our side
